# Handbrake for wheezy?

Tags: debian, software-installation, multimedia

Has anyone figured out how to install/backport a Debian Handbrake package on Debian wheezy? The only version of Handbrake currently in Debian is in experimental, and the dependencies are not available on wheezy, so I can't easily rebuild it. In particular the version of `libav` used is the version in experimental.

The unofficial [deb-multimedia](http://deb-multimedia.org/dists/stable/main/binary-i386/package/handbrake-gtk) repository is a possibility, but I have had problems in the past with its packages being incompatible with Debian. Using a Ubuntu PPA might also be a possibility.

But Linux multimedia is a complicated mess, and I would prefer not to have to mess with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wheezy does not have a Handbrake package. Handbrake is a very useful package. So, what can one do? Debian's only Handbrake package is:

```
apt-cache policy handbrake

handbrake:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.9.9+dfsg-2~2.gbpa4c3e9
  Version table:
     0.9.9+dfsg-2~2.gbpa4c3e9 0
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
```

and I was unable to backport this to wheezy

So, I downloaded the source from `www.deb-multimedia.org`. In general I don't recommend using this site, because the packages are not compatible with Debian packages. However, one can get this Handbrake package to build on wheezy.

```
apt-cache policy handbrake-gtk

handbrake-gtk:
  Installed: 0.9.8+git20121007-dmo6
  Candidate: 0.9.8+git20121007-dmo6
  Version table:
     0.9.8+git20121007-dmo6 0
          1 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 0.9.8+git20121007-dmo6 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Here are the build dependencies from the control file.

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), wget, quilt, libfaac-dev, python,
 libxvidcore-dev, libtheora-dev, libmp3lame-dev, automake, intltool,
 libtool, libbz2-dev, ccache, libmkv-dev (>= 0.6.5.1), libass-dev,
 libsamplerate0-dev, libvorbis-dev, libnotify-dev (>= 0.7.3), libdvdnav-dev,
 libwebkitgtk-dev, libgstreamer0.10-dev, libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev,
 libgudev-1.0-dev [linux-any], libx264-dev (>= 2:0.122.2184+git5c85e0a),
 libdbus-glib-1-dev, yasm [i386 amd64 kfreebsd-i386 kfreebsd-amd64],
 libbluray-dev, libdca-dev, libmpeg2-4-dev, libmp4v2-dev
```

Here are the build dependencies for this package on my system.

```
automake/testing uptodate 1:1.14.1-2
ccache/wheezy uptodate 3.1.7-1
debhelper/wheezy uptodate 9.20120909
intltool/wheezy uptodate 0.50.2-2
libass-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.10.0-3
libbluray-dev/wheezy uptodate 1:0.2.2-1
libbz2-dev/wheezy uptodate 1.0.6-4
libdbus-glib-1-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.100.2-1
libdca-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.0.5-5
libdvdnav-dev/wheezy uptodate 4.2.0+20120524-2
libfaac-dev/wheezy uptodate 1:1.28-dmo3
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.10.36-1.1
libgstreamer0.10-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.10.36-1.2
libgudev-1.0-dev/wheezy uptodate 175-7.2
libmkv-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.6.5.1-dmo3
libmp3lame-dev/wheezy uptodate 3.99.5+repack1-3
libmp4v2-dev/wheezy uptodate 2.0.0~dfsg0-1
libmpeg2-4-dev/squeeze uptodate 0.4.1-3
libnotify-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.7.5-1
libsamplerate0-dev/wheezy uptodate 0.1.8-5
libtheora-dev/wheezy uptodate 1.1.1+dfsg.1-3.1
libtool/wheezy uptodate 2.4.2-1.1
libvorbis-dev/wheezy uptodate 1.3.2-1.3
libwebkitgtk-dev/wheezy uptodate 1.8.1-3.4
libx264-dev/wheezy uptodate 2:0.123.2189+git35cf912-1
libxvidcore-dev/wheezy uptodate 2:1.3.2-9
python/wheezy uptodate 2.7.3-4+deb7u1
quilt/wheezy uptodate 0.60-2
wget/wheezy uptodate 1.13.4-3
yasm/wheezy uptodate 1.1.0-1
```

Except for `libfaac0`, `libfaac-dev`, `libmkv0`, and `libmkv-dev` which I obtained from http://www.deb-multimedia.org/, all these dependencies are satisfied by wheezy. `faac` can be built from the testing sources.
The testing `automake` is not needed here, and `libmpeg2-4-dev` has the same version in squeeze and wheezy.

You do need to make the following change. Replace

```
libx264-dev (>= 3:0.122.2184+git5c85e0a)
```

with

```
libx264-dev (>= 2:0.122.2184+git5c85e0a)
```

in `debian/control`. Then running `debuild -uc -us` should work.

Finally one can install by doing

```
dpkg -i handbrake-gtk_0.9.8+git20121007-dmo6_amd64.deb
```

When installed it looks like

```
ii  handbrake-gtk                         0.9.8+git20121007-dmo6  amd64                   Versatile DVD ripper and video transcoder (GTK GUI).
```

NOTE: this package is (unusually) using Debian source format 1.0. This means, for example, that versioning the source package will cause `dpkg-source` to have fits. Additionally, switching to `3.0 (quilt)` format is non-trivial, because upstream patches are contained in both `debian/patches` and the `diff.gz`. I've sent Christian Marillat a `3.0 (quilt)` version, so maybe he will fix it.

UPDATE: Christian said he was using 1.0 format because his infrastructure does not support 3.0 quilt, and he is unable to upgrade his infrastructure because of technical reasons related to the software he is using.

Comment: I am trying to follow your steps, but I am not an expert here. How do I download the sources? I added `deb-src` to my `sources.list` file, but not sure what to do between this and running `debuild -uc -us`.

Comment: @Grzenio you have enough rep to talk in chat. if you want to talk, shall we go there? Ping me from there if you want. The main Unix.sx chatroom that is.

Comment: @Grzenio Add the `deb-src http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages`, then `apt-get source handbrake-gtk`.

Answer (score 5):

Handbrake is in wheezy-backports now. To install it, add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install handbrake
```

If you get an error message saying that Handbrake breaks libdvdread4, you can upgrade libdvdread4 to the wheezy-backports version:

```
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install libdvdread4
```

Comment: +1 for updated information! Much quicker and less error-prone approach for majority of users. :)

Comment: Thanks, i've tried this and i get this error while converting:  "ERROR: MP4 muxer disabled, exiting". Please advise :)

Comment: MP4 support will be added in 0.10. See [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=695225). Consider using [Matroska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) (.mkv) instead.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 handbrake : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable or
                      libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 6:9.10) but it is not installable
             Depends: libavformat54 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable
             Depends: libavutil52 (>= 6:9.1-1) but it is not installable
             Recommends: gstreamer1.0-libav but it is

Answer (score 2):

A method that worked for me on Debian Wheezy 7.6:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion yasm build-essential autoconf libtool zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libxml2-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libsamplerate-dev libfribidi-dev libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1-dev libass-dev libmp3lame-dev libx264-dev intltool libglib2.0-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libgtk-3-dev libgudev-1.0-dev libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libnotify-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libappindicator-dev libtheora-dev
svn checkout svn://svn.handbrake.fr/HandBrake/trunk hb-trunk
cd hb-trunk
./configure --disable-gtk --launch
cd build
sudo make install
```

I used '--disable-gtk' to build/install [HandBrakeCLI](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide) only.

Also note that you can read about needed dependencies and such in the readme within the svn downloaded files: **hb-trunk/doc/BUILD-Linux**

Comment: Source installation is always an option, but the question is asking about binary packages.

Comment: The source solution worked for me as it has always been. More guide.. https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CompileOnLinux