# Unable to install handbrake on Ubuntu 13.10 via PPA

Tags: ubuntu, ppa

I'm trying to install `handbrake` on my system Ubuntu 13.10 via PPA but not able to do so. I followed [this website](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-handbrake-0-9-9-on-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint-16-15-14-13-elementary-os-0-2-and-pear-os-8/).

I ran the below commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then when I ran `sudo apt-get install handbrake`, I got the error as below.

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo apt-get install handbrake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package handbrake
```

The same error of "unable to locate package handbrake" I got when I used a different PPA got by googling.

What's the issue here!!

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87066/4671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're following the wrong instructions. The page you linked to provides the following instructions for Ubuntu 13.10 (64 bit):

```
$ wget -c https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases/+files/handbrake-gtk_0.9.9ppa1~raring1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i handbrake-gtk_0.9.9ppa1~raring1_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

The ones you followed, using the PPA, are for older versions of Ubuntu. Presumably, the PPA you are attempting to use does not have a section for 13.10 so when you try to run `apt-get install handbrake`, no package is found.