# Installing handbrake on Debian - Wheezy server

Tags: debian, command-line, webserver, debian-installer

I'm trying to install the handbrake CLI onto my debian(wheezy) server. I've tried to imitate an answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87066/handbrake-for-wheezy) but it is not working.

I've added `deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main` to the sources list in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

and got the output after running an apt-get update and the actual install command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install handbrake
```

but I receive the following errors:

```
user@web:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
user@web:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy Release                                   
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates Release                           
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid Release.gpg                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release.gpg                                
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates Release                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release                                    
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid Release                                  
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main Sources                             
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main Translation-en               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources                               
  404  Not Found
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main amd64 Packages                      
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main Translation-en_US                   
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main Translation-en                 
Get:1 http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports Release.gpg [1,554 B]
Get:2 http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports Release [144 kB]
Get:3 http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages [571 kB]
Get:4 http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports/main Translation-en [363 kB] 
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release.gpg                              
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Sources  
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US                   
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en                      
Fetched 1,080 kB in 9s (116 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
user@web:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
user@web:~$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
Use "fg" to return to nano.

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
user@web:~$ sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install libdvdread4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libdvdcss2
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdvdread4
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.
Need to get 57.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy-backports/main libdvdread4 amd64 4.2.1-2~bpo70+1 [57.4 kB]
Fetched 57.4 kB in 0s (576 kB/s)       
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 65274 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libdvdread4 4.2.0+20120521-2 (using .../libdvdread4_4.2.1-2~bpo70+1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdvdread4:amd64 ...
Setting up libdvdread4:amd64 (4.2.1-2~bpo70+1) ...
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ sid/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.deb-multimedia.org_dists_sid_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
user@web:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release                                    
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy Release.gpg                               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy Release                                   
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates Release                           
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid Release.gpg                              
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates Release                           
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid Release                                  
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main Sources                              
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources                               
  404  Not Found
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main amd64 Packages                      
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages                       
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main Translation-en_US                   
Hit http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports Release.gpg                        
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main Translation-en
Hit http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports Release
Hit http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://cdn.debian.net wheezy-backports/main Translation-en
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Sources
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US                   
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en                      
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
user@web:~$ sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backgports install handbrake
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ sid/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.deb-multimedia.org_dists_sid_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The value 'wheezy-backgports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Here is the contents of my sources.list:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.4.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 $

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.4.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 $

deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid main
```

Latest errors:

```
user@web:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy Release                                   
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates Release                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release.gpg                 
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates Release                           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release                                    
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main Sources                              
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid Release.gpg                              
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy/updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid Release                                  
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://mirrors.linode.com wheezy-updates/main Translation-en  
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources                  
  404  Not Found
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main amd64 Packages         
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en_US       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en          
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main Translation-en_US     
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org sid/main Translation-en
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Sources
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US                   
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en                      
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
user@web:~$ sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install handbrake
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'wheezy-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

Can anyone help me with a solution? Forgive me as i'm trying to get to grips with CLI's!

Comment: That can't be everything. Please also show us the contents of any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Also show us the errors you are getting now.

Comment: sources.list.d doesn't exist

Comment: @terdon i've added the latest errors

Comment: OK, you still haven't removed the PPA, that's the source of some of the errors. If you have no `sources.list.d`, I'm not sure where you have it. Try running `grep -RH ppa /etc/apt/`. That should show you which file points to the PPA. I also don't understand why you're using `wheezy-backports` in the first place. Why not just `apt-get install handbrake`?

Comment: @terdon I was researching and a lot of sources say that there is not a convenient way of installing handbrake cli to a debian wheezy setup.

Comment: @terdon the result of `grep -RH ppa /etc/apt/` is : `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stebbins-handbrake-releases-wheezy.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu wheezy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stebbins-handbrake-releases-wheezy.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu wheezy main`

Comment: Then `sources.list.d` exists, why did you say it didn't? It would be much easier to debug this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux), come ping me there.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues here.

1. Debian doesn't support Ubuntu PPAs. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the PPA.
2. You have duplicate entries. Either in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. You need to edit the file and remove the duplicates for `deb-multimedia.org`. Run `grep -H deb-multimedia  /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and delete one of the dupes.
3. You have a typo. Note the error:

   ```
   E: The value 'wheezy-backgports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
   ```

   You meant `backports`, not `backgports`.

Comment: I've added the sources.list contents above

Comment: I've adjusted as you said but I now receive more errors. Pleas see above. Thanks!